# Removing XML declaration in WS request

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, xml-declaration

I'm trying to consume a third part Web Service using **JAX-WS** (com.sun.xml.ws.jaxws-rt, version 2.2.10). In all my tests, the XML declaration `<?xml version="1.0" ?>` is automatically sent.

Is it possible to remove this? I tried to put *javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION* as *false* in the request context (obtained through *javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider*), but it has no effects.

Before someone asks, remove the XML declaration from request is required by the WS owner.

Thanks.

Comment: May be you could expand on your Jax-WS implementation and JAXB version ? What is the package of the `SOAPMessage` class you are talking about ?

Comment: @GPI I edited the question with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question: after many hours of researching, readings and frustrated attempts, I think removing XML declaration with **JAXWS** is just **impossible**.

So, I decided to try with **CFX** as WS provider. I just put the *cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws* module in project and the comunication works fine, without the XML declaration by default.

[edited] More details could be seen here: https://brunozambiazi.wordpress.com/2015/12/18/removing-xml-declaration-in-ws-request/